# zipping with code entire folder not able to un-zip

Tags: go

I use the following code to zip entire folder and I see the outcome i.e. the zip artifacts that created , Now I want to **unzip** it with the mac zip apps and I got the following  error

[image]
The code that I use for zip this folder is:
what I miss here ? or there is better approach to do it in Golang ?

```
func zipit(source, target string) error {
    zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()

    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }

    filepath.Walk(source, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unzipping it on the cli? Are you trying to overwrite files? Do you have permission to unzip in the target directory? Can you list the zip contents? Do you have any special types of files in the archive?

Comment: @JimB didnt try to unzip in the cli , let me know how and I try it . this is a simple zip with just 10 html files

Comment: @JimB - yes I have permission to unzip in the target directory

Comment: check `unzip -t archive.zip` it would tell you your archive is broken in any way...

Comment: @biosckon - Thanks I've tried it and I got message at the end `"No errors detected in compressed data of ui5.zip."` , but I dont see that unzip folder, why ? where I can find it?

Comment: @biosckon - I've tried with `unzip ui5.zip  -d dir123` and I see the the unzip folder but at the end I got error `symlink error: File name too long
lchmod (file attributes) error: No such file or directory` , any idea what it could be ?

Comment: @shopiaT there seems to be a problem with the data that you have in the folder. Try out your code on something simple (it works for me). A single folder with one small file. If that works then gradually work with reduced copies of your problematic folder. Meaning make bunch of copies of your original folder delete some of it's content and test what exactly causes that error. As your error says - you'll likely find some symlink that is not handled correctly.

Comment: @shopiaT have you tried to zip with your code and with something like winrar and then open both in notepad++ to look for differences?

with my first program my code added 8 bytes somewhere it created a zip file the caused no errors but could still not be oppend properly

Answer (score 0):

Because reimplementations of the command line tools are far slower, it's best to just use `exec.Command`. Once the archive is created, then you can read it in and send it where you like.

```
func main() {
    pwd := os.Getenv("PWD")
    dest := pwd + "/testdir.zip"
    src := pwd + "/testdir"

    err := Zip(src, dest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func Zip(src, dest string) error {
    zipper := exec.Command("zip", "-rj", dest, src)
    fmt.Println(zipper.Args)
    err := zipper.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

note: this may be different depending on your OS. This runs for me on OSX.